# Database schema for a settings type table that can have different data types

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm currently trying to create a database schema for a small project of mine and I've come upon a bit of a roadblock. I want to have a Settings table that will store my different settings. My problem is the settings can have different data types: int, varchar, bool, datetime.

The easiest solution would be to make everything varchar but I wanted to ask if there are other design alternatives I could take.

Comment: Have you considered sql_variant?

Comment: @DanGuzman: I would want to be able to store them in their actual data type, even if it means adding several more tables.

Comment: You could have an xml column; that will allow for easy changes in the future to add different settings of different datatypes or store some setting values for some columns and other setting values for other columns.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to want to store data with the appropriate type in the database so data doesn't get clobbered, especially sensitive things like decimals where i18n could potentially cause a problem.

What I've done in the past is create a table with the setting name, data type, and then value columns of each relevant type. Then either in a UDF or your application code, have it dynamically get/set using the right column.

For example:

```
create table settings (
    id            int identity(1,1) primary key,
    name          sysname not null,
    value_type    varchar(20) not null,

    int_value     int           not null default 0,
    decimal_value decimal(10,2) not null default 0,
    bool_value    bit           not null default 0,
    string_value  nvarchar(max) null
)
create unique index IX_settings on settings (name);
go

create function dbo.GetSetting(@name sysname) returns sql_variant as
begin;
    declare @retval sql_variant;
    select
        @retval = case value_type
            when 'int'     then int_value
            when 'bool'    then bool_value
            when 'string'  then string_value
            when 'decimal' then decimal_value
        end
    from settings
    where name = @name;

    return @retval;
end;
go

insert into settings (name, value_type, int_value) values ('limit', 'int', 10);
insert into settings (name, value_type, bool_value) values ('enabled', 'bool', 1);
insert into settings (name, value_type, decimal_value) values ('rate', 'decimal', 9884.45);
select dbo.GetSetting('limit'), dbo.GetSetting('enabled'), dbo.GetSetting('rate')
```

As for writing the data, you could do that with a stored procedure or in your application code.